# AngularJS Injector - Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootScopeProvider <- $rootScope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

May be it's trivial question, but for AngularJS newbie it's a matter ^_^

What I'm trying to originally achieve is to make a dynamically inserted tag (by jQuery) with ng-click directive to work. I've searched and found that I've to get AngularJS Injector, then compile that code. So here it is the simplest form of the injector code which is NOT working for me, what's wrong with it?

Note #1: The dynamically inserted tag with ngDirective is done outside AngularJS scope.

```
angular.module('simpleExample', [])
.run(
  [ '$rootScope',
  function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.test = "Test";
  }]);

console.log(angular.injector(['simpleExample']));

// console.log(angular.injector(['simpleExample']).$compile('<a href="" ng-click="someFunctionOnRootScope()">Text</a>'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zx8hr/6/

Answer (score 3):

#### The `ng` module

- `angular.bootstrap` automatically adds the `ng` module to the dependencies when used (manually or with `ngApp`)
- `$rootScope` / `$compile` services are part of the `ng` module.
- You need to use `injector.invoke` if you want these services.
- You should probably use angular in more traditional ways.

#### Try this:

```
angular.module('simpleExample', ['ng']);

angular.injector(['simpleExample'])
  .invoke(['$rootScope','$compile', 
    function($rootScope, $compile){

      var elm = $compile('<a href="" ng-click="someFunctionOnRootScope()">Text</a>')($rootScope);
      $rootScope.someFunctionOnRootScope = function(){
          alert("Hello there!");
      }
      angular.element(document.body).append(elm);

}]);
```

Comment: Well, I don't care the UI router at the mean time. I've removed the state code from my snippet now.. What I care about is the compile/injector thing, how to make it work from outside scope?

Comment: Probably needs another $apply wrap considering the call will come from outside angularjs. This was my attempt http://jsfiddle.net/Zx8hr/9/.

Comment: ooh, In my example I just bound the `test` variable, and that needed the `$apply`. :)